# Working with c++ dll and wpf

Tags: c++, dll, reference, serial-port

I have c++ dll with header file

```
#ifndef NETRRSWIN_H
  #define NETRRSWIN_H

enum ErrorType
  {
  COMM_OK            ,
  BAD_BAUD_RATE      ,
  PORT_ALREADY_OPEN  ,
  PORT_NOT_OPEN      ,
  OPEN_ERROR         ,
  WRITE_ERROR        ,
  READ_ERROR         ,
  CLOSE_ERROR        ,
  RWPARAMS_ERROR
  };

extern __declspec( dllexport ) char GetRxBuffer( unsigned char *TargetAddr, unsigned char *NumOfBytes );
extern __declspec( dllexport ) unsigned char GetByte(void);
extern __declspec( dllexport ) int  RxBufferBytesAvailable(void);
extern __declspec( dllexport ) void DiscardRxBytes( unsigned char MaxBytes );
extern __declspec( dllexport ) char LoadTxBuffer( unsigned char *SourceAddr, unsigned char NumOfBytes );
extern __declspec( dllexport ) char SetSysCommPort( char *COMname );
extern __declspec( dllexport ) char SetSysBaudRate( unsigned int BaudRate );
extern __declspec( dllexport ) char CloseSysCommPort(void);
extern __declspec( dllexport ) char ResetSysCommPort(void);

#endif
```

Which i imported to my project (with always copy option).

Also I've imported those methods from dll as

```
 [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char GetRxBuffer(char TargetAddr, char NumOfBytes);
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char GetByte(string rva);
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern int RxBufferBytesAvailable();
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern void DiscardRxBytes(char MaxBytes);
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char LoadTxBuffer(char SourceAddr, char NumOfBytes);
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char SetSysCommPort(char COMname);
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char SetSysBaudRate(int BaudRate);
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char CloseSysCommPort();
        [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
        public static extern char ResetSysCommPort();
```

Problem is that, when I'm trying to open port using SetSysCommPort I'm getting this error:

> Error Message: Procedure Entry Point Not Found in NetrRsWin.dll File

What is best way to use c++ dll in WPF? Also I've tried to load dll as reference, but it says it is not valid com reference.

Thanks

Comment: Your functions signatures in .Net are wrong. E.g. `char *` and `char`. Have you created these yourself?

Comment: I have just copied them from header file, but even if I change them it still doesnt work

Comment: You have to use the decorated name, you can see them with `dumpbin.exe /exports`.  And use the CallingConvention property, it looks like Cdecl.  And use the proper types in the pinvoke declarations.

Comment: I don't think this question has ***absolutely*** anything to do with WPF, unless WPF has a different acronym than `Windows Presentation Foundation` that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

`Char*` in C++ and `char` in C# are not the same type. So the SetSysCommPort signature is not correct. It should be:

```
    [DllImport("NetrRsWin.dll")]
    public static extern char SetSysCommPort([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String COMname);
```

You should check the other methods signatures too.

Comment: Your signature is wrong too. It has to be a `StringBuilder`, not a `string`. Or, you have to specify something like `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `MarshalAs` attribute, but I'm not sure that it is possible to use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`